# Print a png file however can't seem to print

Tags: c#

Good day! I was trying to print a png file using a Picturebox as my button.
However, I can't seem to print. Could you please help me? or Give me a link that will guide me on how to print on a default printer using C# VS 2010

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
    {
        using (PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog())
        {
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
                pd.Print();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

    System.Drawing.Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Coke\res10.png");
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0,0); 
}
```

Comment: What is error you are getting?

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution for this.

```
 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
 pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
 {
       Image i = Image.FromFile("C://tesimage.PNG");
       args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, args.PageBounds);

 };
 pd.Print();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple one, but easy to miss..

You are doing just about everything right. Just one tiny thing is not `'OK'`:

You need to change

```
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes)
```

to

```
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

It is not a question, after all, so it shows 'OK' and 'Cancel' not 'Yes' and 'No'.